# Using Garena lol files to play in Oceania server

Tags: league-of-legends

I was playing LoL on Garena for 1 year.Then I wanted to change my region and I knew I can't transfer my account to Riot server. So I created an account on the Lol official website,and downloaded the installer etc. The problem is...I don't want to download another folder of LOL files on my computer. Can anyone help me to let my Oceania client use my Garena lol files to play?

Comment: Not sure what/if Garena is doing anything to your files. If Garena performs any changes, then you have no way around it (I assume). If those are the original files, then you should be able to point either Garena to the new LoL files or the new client to the old LoL files. Just like you can add non-steam games to steam or reinstall a game in Origin when you already got the files

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, it is not possible.

Long answer: No (see below).

Garena and Riot don't share the same client, even if the codebase of the related files are similar. This is because they run on completely different environments - one uses the Garena client and the other uses the Riot launcher, which is what you see on the login screen. So that's one difference already - the login procedure is completely different. And that is one reason why it is incompatible, along with other reasons like localization and not running on identical patches.